# Node's process.stdin readable stream logs Null when read inside a readable event listener callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, command-line-interface

Without making use of a `data` event, I want this code to log the unicode reference of each key as I press it down. I can't understand why I'm getting `Null` everytime.

Whenever I press down a key on my keyboard I'll fire a readable event on `process.stdin` running a callback which allows me to read data from this readable stream. So why it isn't holding any data from my keypresses?

```
// nodo.js

function nodo() { 
  var stdin = process.stdin;
  var stdout = process.stdout;

  if (stdin.isTTY) {
    stdin.setRawMode(true);
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.resume();
    stdout.write('\u000A>Bienvenido\u000A');      
  } else {
    process.exit();
  }

  stdin.on('readable', function(){

    var input = stdin.read();
    console.log(input);

  });
}

nodo();
```

[image: running the code]

I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a read of [that document](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)
that explains how to correctly handle `process.stdin`. Your mistake was to use `stdin.resume`
that enables the "old" compatibility mode on process stdin streams.

```
// nodo.js

function nodo() { 
    var stdin = process.stdin;
    var stdout = process.stdout;

    if (stdin.isTTY) {
        stdin.setRawMode(true);
        stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
        stdout.write('\u000A>Bienvenido\u000A');      

        process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

        process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
            var chunk = process.stdin.read();
            if (chunk !== null) {
                process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
            }
        });

        process.stdin.on('end', function() {
            process.stdout.write('end');
        });
    } else {
        process.exit();
    }
}

nodo();
```